# Reading, modifying and writing a geotiff with GDAL in python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, landsat, numpy

I'm trying the learn the ropes of Remote Sensing image processing using Python GDAL bindings and numpy. As a first attempt, I'm reading a Landsat8 geotiff file, do a simple manipulation and write the result to a new file. The code below appears to work fine, except that the original raster is dumped in the output file, rather than the manipulated raster.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome, but particularly notes on why the manipulated raster does not show in the result.

```
import os
import gdal

gdal.AllRegister()

file = "c:\~\LC81980242015071LGN00.tiff"
(fileRoot, fileExt) = os.path.splitext(file)
outFileName = fileRoot + "_mod" + fileExt

ds = gdal.Open(file)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()

[cols, rows] = arr.shape
arr_min = arr.Min()
arr_max = arr.Max()
arr_mean = int(arr.mean())

arr_out = numpy.where((arr < arr_mean), 10000, arr)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outdata = driver.Create(outFileName, rows, cols, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
outband = outdata.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(arr_out)
outdata = None

print arr_min
> 0
print arr_max
> 65535
print arr_mean
> 4856
```

I use Python 2.7.1 on a Windows 7 32 bit machine.

Comment: I got it to work on a DEM (Ubuntu, python 2.7.1) and it produced the expected result, with everything below the mean value set to 10000 and written to a new tiff. You're not copying the geotransform over to the new image so it's unprojected, so you might need to factor that in when trying to view it (there's a one-liner to do this but I'll need to dig it out). If you can edit your question with the output from `gdainfo -stats original.tiff` and `gdal-config --version` too that could help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this! I know I neglected the geotransform, thought to chew on that later. I do see the entire output image though (using Irfanview), so that can't be it I think. I'll generate the info you requested when I'm back on seat tonight.

Comment: Hi, I'm struggling to provide the info you asked. I'm using Python GDAL binding and I'm unsure how the commands you specifiy correspond to a Python command. In any case, I'm using GDAL-1.11.2-cp27-none-win32, as acquired from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I'll update my post with some stats on the original .tiff.

Comment: what would arr_min be?

Comment: arr_min = 0. I've updated the post to show this. Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of issues with Steven's advice:
You need to run gdalinfo -stats original.tff and gdal-config is only available on a unix installation from memory.

Copy your original tiff to the location of GDALINFO (should be GDAL_HOME\bin\gdal\apps and then run the gdalinfo -stats 'tiff file name' and post that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your script is missing the ds.FlushCache method, that saves to disk what you have in memory at the end of the modifications. See below a corrected version of your example. Notice that I also added two lines to set projection and geotransform as input

```
import os
import gdal

file = "path+filename"
ds = gdal.Open(file)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()
[rows, cols] = arr.shape
arr_min = arr.min()
arr_max = arr.max()
arr_mean = int(arr.mean())
arr_out = numpy.where((arr < arr_mean), 10000, arr)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outdata = driver.Create(outFileName, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())##sets same geotransform as input
outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())##sets same projection as input
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr_out)
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(10000)##if you want these values transparent
outdata.FlushCache() ##saves to disk!!
outdata = None
band=None
ds=None
```

Comment: The outfile is not projected. I am reading an HDF5 file and select the projection from the band which I want to export `GetProjection()` delivers the correct EPSG, but it seems to be not applied. GDAL warp missing? Thanks!

Comment: what should I replace with `outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr_out)` to write a multispectral image that has more than one band?

Comment: The "1" in driver.Create() indicates the number of bands. Then you can write on each band with outdata.GetRasterBand(band_number). It starts at 1, not zero.

Comment: I would add that you also can define the width and height of the array using ds.RasterXSize and ds.RasterYSize